# Union of good feature sets degrades accuracy

Tags: python, feature-selection, scikit-learn, text-mining, information-retrieval

I am doing binary text classification and I have some feature sets (unigrams, bigrams, dependencies, etc.) and each one of these performs very good individually. For example unigrams alone achieve 89% accuracy and bigrams alone 87% accuracy with 10 Fold CV. But the problem is that when I combine them the accuracy is around 88% which is worse than unigrams alone.

My idea was that by combining good features I will get better results.

Here is one simple Pipeline combining unigrams and bigrams:

```
Pipeline([
    ('features', FeatureUnion(
        transformer_list=[
            ('bot-1', Pipeline([
                ('ext', TextFeatureExtractor(feat_type="bot", term="word", negation=True)),
                ('vec', CountVectorizer(min_df=0.003, max_df=0.9, lowercase=False)),
                ("fs", SelectKBest(score_func=mutual_info_classif, k=10000)),
                ('bin', Binarizer()),
                ('trans', TfidfTransformer(sublinear_tf=True, smooth_idf=True, use_idf=True)),
            ])),
            ('bot-2', Pipeline([
                ('ext', TextFeatureExtractor(feat_type="bot", term="lemma", negation=True)),
                ('vec', CountVectorizer(min_df=0.002, max_df=0.9, lowercase=False, ngram_range=(2, 2))),
                ("fs", SelectKBest(score_func=mutual_info_classif, k=15000)),
                ('bin', Binarizer()),
                ('trans', TfidfTransformer(sublinear_tf=True, smooth_idf=True, use_idf=True)),
            ])),
        ],
    )),
    ('classifier', svm.LinearSVC(C=.5)),
])
```

As you can see I do MI Feature Selection and after that I apply tf-idf transformation on the selected features. Am I doing something wrong?

The things I have tried so far:

- Scale them using `StandardScaler(with_mean=False)`  before classification
- Scale them using `MaxAbsScaler()`  before classification
- apply `TruncatedSVD` with `n_components`= 100-300 after the `TfidfTransformer` and also tried normalization after that.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How many observations are in your dataset? Have you tried other models? Have you tried changing the regularization parameter of your SVC?

Comment: Try normalizing (L_2 normalization) everything, just before applying the classifier. Also, try various values of C for Logistic Regression, e.g., [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, ..,100 ]